# collect previous kernel logs in linux after reboot

Tags: linux, kernel

how to collect previous kernel logs in linux after reboot and
how to search the old logs?

Initially when system is rebooted the logs are not captured and found rest of the log's.But there is an error in the previous log which is not captured???

Comment: Three places to check; Output from the `dmesg` command, the  `/var/log/boot.log`, and `/var/log/messages` (Note: It would be helpful if you mentioned / tagged your actual Linux distribution in your question)

Comment: Also, `dmesg` output may already be caught-up in `/var/log/dmesg.log` (Depending on your Linux distribution).  If not, it's a simple thing to put in an `rc.local` script (`dmesg >> /var/log/dmesg.log`), and you might want to include that in the log-rotation so it doesn't endlessly append to the file.